# How to add a constraint which requires an integer variable belongs to an array?

Tags: python, z3, smt, z3py

Suppose I have a [z3py](https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/guide-examples.htm) integer variable `x = Int('x')`, and an integer array `a = [1, 2, 3]`. Then I add a constraint through s.add(x in a).

I think this is satisfiable because `x` can be `1 or 2 or 3`. But it's unsitisfiable actually. Can anyone tell me how can I add a constraint to make sure `x in a`?

Thanks!

Here is the python code I used. I thought the output answer would be s is satisfiable, because x can be equal to 1 or 2 or 3, then the constraint `x in a` is satisfied. But the answer is actually unsat. Maybe this is not the right method to specify this constraint. So my question is how to specify such a constraint to make sure a variable can only be instantiated with the value in a specific array.

```
from z3 import *
x = Int('x')

a = [1, 2, 3]

s = Solver()

s.add(x in a)

print(s.check())
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: This doesn't look like a full example of what your code does: what are you actually trying to achieve that you think requires using a number list, instead of using `solve` with adequately defined `<` and `>` constraints?

Comment: @timgeb the "z3" and "z3py" tags are fairly essential here. https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/guide-examples.htm

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans ah, thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: what is `s`? in `s.add(x in a)`

Comment: Sorry! let me give the example code here:

Comment: from z3 import *
x = Int('x')

a = [1, 2, 3]

s = Solver()

s.add(x in a)

print(s.check())

Comment: @Francis edit the example into your question, please. The comments don't support code longer than a line or so.

Comment: @Francis don't add your code as one, or more, comments. Edit your post and put the code there, as per the ["how to ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) policy article. And if you've not read that, take a minute to read it first, because it's an important policy article to read before you post questions.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks! I'm actually a beginner. Sorry about that!

Comment: No worries - but I'm still curious what you're trying to _do_ here. Are you just trying to use `z3` and seeing what it can do, or are you working on something that requires resolving `x` to 1, 2, and 3? Because if it's the first then it's really a matter of "don't do this, just solve with the constraint that `x>0` and `x<4` instead of using a list of predefined numbers".

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I am working on something that requires this functionality.  If the array is [1, 4, 7], then I don't know other methods to specify such a constraint.

Comment: In line with the policy article: that's excellent information to also put in your post should you need to ask questions in the future: make sure that if it looks like you're doing something that has an obvious simpler solution, explain why you can't use that solution =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do:

```
from z3 import *

a = [1,2,3]

s = Solver()
x = Int('x')
s.add(Or([x == i for i in a]))

# Enumerate all possible solutions:
while True:
    r = s.check()
    if r == sat:
        m = s.model()
        print m
        s.add(x != m[x])
    else:
        print r
        break
```

When I run this, I get:

```
[x = 1]
[x = 2]
[x = 3]
unsat
```

Answer (score 0):

"x in a" is a python expression, that evaluates to False before you assert the constraint, since the variable x does not belong to the array.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to build an `z3.And` or `z3.Or` constraint using a loop

```
# Finds all numbers in the domain, for which it's square is also in the domain

import z3
exclude = [1,2]
domain  = list(range(128))
number  = z3.Int('number')
squared = number * number
solver  = z3.Solver()
solver.add(z3.Or([  number  == value for value in domain  ]))
solver.add(z3.Or([  squared == value for value in domain  ]))
solver.add(z3.And([ number  != value for value in exclude ]))
solver.add(z3.And([ squared != value for value in exclude ]))
solver.push()  # create stack savepoint

output = []
while solver.check() == z3.sat:
  value = solver.model()[number].as_long()
  solver.add( number != value )
  output.append(value)

solver.pop()  # reset stack to last solver.push()

print(output)
# [10, 0, 4, 6, 5, 11, 9, 8, 3, 7]

print(sorted(output))
# [0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```